# How to add a logarithmic nonlinear fit to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls

I'd like to fit the logarithmic curve through my data using `nls`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
a <- 3
b <- 2
Y <- data_frame(x = c(0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10),
                y = a + b*log(x))

Y %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(shape = 19, size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(method = "nls",
              formula = y ~ p1 + p2*log(x),
              start = list(a = a, b = b),
              se = FALSE,
              control = list(maxiter = 100))
```

This gives me an error:

> Error in method(formula, data = data, weights = weight, ...) : 
>     number of iterations exceeded maximum of 100

What is going wrong?

Comment: you probably want to add a tiny bit of noise to the y value since you are minimizing error, `y = a + b*log(x) + rnorm(6, 0, 0.001)`.  Then, make `start=list(p1=a, p2=b)`

Comment: BTW, note that, at least in the example you are providing, the model is linear in the parameters; in other words, at least in this example you don't need `nls`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some text I copied and pasted after doing `?nls`:

> **Warning**
>
> Do not use nls on artificial "zero-residual" data.
>
> The nls function uses a relative-offset convergence criterion that compares the numerical imprecision at the current parameter estimates to the residual sum-of-squares. This performs well on data of the form
>
> y = f(x, θ) + eps
>
> (with var(eps) > 0). It fails to indicate convergence on data of the form
>
> y = f(x, θ)
>
> because the criterion amounts to comparing two components of the round-off error. If you wish to test nls on artificial data please add a noise component, as shown in the example below.

That inspired me to try this:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(ggplot2)
> a <- 3
> b <- 2
> Y <- data_frame(x = c(0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10),
+                 y = a + b*log(x)*(1 + rnorm(length(x), sd=0.001)))
> Y %>%
+   ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
+   geom_point(shape = 19, size = 2) +
+   geom_smooth(method = "nls",
+               formula = y ~ p1 + p2*log(x),
+               start = list(p1 = a, p2 = b),
+               se = FALSE,
+               control = list(maxiter = 100))
```

Note: your code had `start = list(a=a, b=b)` which is a typo because `a` and `b` aren't defined in your formula.  Aside from that, adding the `*(1 + rnorm(length(x), sd=0.001))` is the only thing I did.

The resulting graph made it seem like everything worked fine.

[image: Plot of results]

I'd generally recommend doing the fit separately, however, and then plotting it with `predict`.  That way you can always check the quality of the fit to see if it worked before plotting.

```
> fit <- nls(data=Y, formula = y ~ p1 + p2*log(x), start = list(p1 = a, p2 = b))
> summary(fit)

Formula: y ~ p1 + p2 * log(x)

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
p1 3.001926   0.001538    1952 4.14e-13 ***
p2 1.999604   0.001114    1795 5.78e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.003619 on 4 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.623e-08

> new_x = data.frame(x=seq(from=0.2, to=10, length.out=100))
> ggplot(data=Y, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       geom_line(data=new_x, 
                 aes(x=new_x, y=predict(fit, newdata=new_x)), 
                 color='blue')
```